# How to embed button with Vue code into cell inserted with insertCell()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have Vue component with a table with users data:

```
<table class="worker-table" id="worker-table">
  <tr>
    <th><b>Phone number</b></th>
    <th><b>Debet card</b></th>
    <th><b>Money</b></th>
    <th><b>Work hours</b></th>
    <th><b>Responsible</b></th>
    <th><b>Delete</b></th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  
  <tr v-for="worker in workers">
    <td >
      <div v-if="worker.parent == 1">
        <strong v-on:click="toggleChildWorkers(worker)" class="pointer">
          {{worker.phone}}(+{{child_workers[worker.id].length}})
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        {{worker.phone}}
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>{{worker.debit_card}}</td>
    <td>{{worker.money}}</td>
    <td>{{worker.work_hours}}</td>
    <td>{{worker.responsible_for_money}}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"
         v-bind:disabled="(application.state > CLOSED_ST)? true: false"
         class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
         v-on:click="deleteEntry(worker.id)"
      >
        Delete
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The button in the last `<td>` successfully deletes worker from the table.
Function toggleChildWorkers insert new rows with child workers and delete (hide, actually) them like this:

```
toggleChildWorkers(parentWorker)
{
  var table = document.getElementById("worker-table");
  var childWorkers = this.child_workers[parentWorker.id];
  var childWorkersCount = childWorkers.length;
  var parentWorkersIndexes = this.openAccordionsIndexes;
  var dI = 0;
  var userWantsCloseThisAccordion = false;
  var indexOfClosingAcc = -1;

  console.log(parentWorker);

  for (var j = 0; j < parentWorkersIndexes.length; j++)
  {
    if (parentWorkersIndexes[j] < parentWorker.index)
    {
      dI += this.openAccordionsStrCount[j];
    }
    else if (parentWorkersIndexes[j] == parentWorker.index)
    {
      userWantsCloseThisAccordion = true;
      indexOfClosingAcc = j;
    }
  }

  if (userWantsCloseThisAccordion)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.openAccordionsStrCount[indexOfClosingAcc]; i++)
    {
      table.deleteRow(parentWorker.index + 3 + dI);
    }
    this.openAccordionsIndexes.splice(indexOfClosingAcc, 1);
    this.openAccordionsStrCount.splice(indexOfClosingAcc, 1);
    return;
  }

  this.openAccordionsIndexes.push(parentWorker.index);
  this.openAccordionsStrCount.push(childWorkersCount);

  for (var i = 0; i < childWorkersCount; i++)
  {
    var row = table.insertRow(parentWorker.index + 3 + dI + i);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.style.cssText = this.styleOfOpenAccStrings;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.style.cssText = this.styleOfOpenAccStrings;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.style.cssText = this.styleOfOpenAccStrings;

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell4.style.cssText = this.styleOfOpenAccStrings;

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell5.style.cssText = this.styleOfOpenAccStrings;

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    cell6.style.cssText = this.styleOfOpenAccStrings;

    cell1.innerHTML = (childWorkers[i].phone === undefined) ?
      '' : childWorkers[i].phone;
    cell2.innerHTML = (childWorkers[i].debit_card === undefined) ?
      '' : childWorkers[i].debit_card;
    cell3.innerHTML = (childWorkers[i].money === undefined) ?
      '' : childWorkers[i].money;
    cell4.innerHTML = (childWorkers[i].work_hours === undefined) ?
      '' : childWorkers[i].work_hours;
    cell5.innerHTML = childWorkers[i].responsible_for_money;
    cell6.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\"\n" +
      "                         v-bind:disabled=\"(application.state > CLOSED_ST)? true: false\"\n" +
      "                         class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\"\n" +
      "                         v-on:click=\"deleteEntry(props.row.index)\"\n" +
      "                      >";

    row.className = "openAccordionRow";
  }
},
```

As you can see, I'm trying to embed buttons in the new cells of inserted rows (blue ones). But they are not displayed as it was intended and don't work at all.

[image]

How can I embed button with Vue code into new cell of inserted row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315315/how-do-i-add-a-button-to-a-td-using-js). But I did't understand it at the beginning and use it **without closure** and it did't work as I expected. Then I found topic about [Javascript infamous loop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)
and used the closure magic:

```
for (var i = 0; i < childWorkersCount; i++)
{
    /* ...
       ...
       ...
    */

    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.className = "btn btn-xs btn-danger";
    btn.value = "Delete " + childWorkers[i].phone;

    var app = this;
    var parentId = parentWorker.id;

    btn.onclick = function (worker) {
        return function () {
            app.deleteEntryById(worker.id, parentId);
        };
    }(childWorkers[i]);
}
```